# Route not defined when it is the same way as the others

Tags: php, laravel

The current stage of this project is to have a document upload system on a website where someone could upload a document, download, view and makes notes on it. I have all import, delete and download sorted however when creating the View  route and view I am getting

```
Route [documents.view] not defined. (View: C:\projects\mcdonaldscosting\resources\views\documents\index.blade.php)
```

I have tried renaming it, changing it to go directly to a function and the path of the route and cant figure this out because its identical as the others I am using.

web.php

```
Route::get('/documents', 'DocumentsController@index')->name('documents.index');
Route::post('/documents/import', 'DocumentsController@import');
Route::get('/documents/{document}', 'DocumentsController@view')->name('documents.view');
Route::delete('/documents/{document}', 'DocumentsController@delete')->name('documents.delete');
Route::get('/documents/{document}', 'DocumentsController@download')->name('documents.download');
```

documents/index.blade.php

```
@if(sizeof($documents))
            @foreach ($documents as $document)
                <tr>

                    <td>{{ $document->title }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $document->ext }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $document->size }}</td>
                    <form class="mt-3" method="GET" action="{{ route('documents.view', ['document' => $document]) }}">
                        @csrf
                        <td>
                            <button data-confirm="true" class="btn btn-info btn-block" type="submit">View</button>
                        </td>
                    </form>
                    <form class="mt-3" method="GET" action="{{ route('documents.download', ['document' => $document]) }}">
                        @csrf
                        <td>
                            <button data-confirm="true" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Download</button>
                        </td>
                    </form>

                    <form class="mt-3" method="POST" action="{{ route('documents.delete', ['document' => $document]) }}">
                        @csrf
                        @method('DELETE')
                    <td>
                        <button data-confirm="true" data-message="Are you sure you want to delete {{ $document->title }}? This cannot be undone!" class="btn btn-danger btn-block" type="submit">Delete</button>
                    </td>
                    </form>


                </tr>
            @endforeach
```

DocumentsController.php

```
    public function view(Document $document) {


        return route('documents.view');
    }
```

I don't understand how this can work with my other routes and views and this one it doesn't.

Comment: You have two GET routes with the same URI '/documents/{document}' only one is registered

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the same route with a different name:

```
Route::get('/documents/{document}', 'DocumentsController@view')->name('documents.view');
// the same as this
Route::get('/documents/{document}', 'DocumentsController@download')->name('documents.download');
```

It get's overridden by the one below, so change the endpoint.

Comment: Nakov, it's better not to post answers to typo questions. You could have helped the OP in comments and voted to close afterwards. This Q&A won't help any future users. Over 8k rep, you should know these things. :)

Comment: @yivi is it really a typo, or someone else might think that you can have the same URI and just having the route name different will work?

Comment: IMHO it's a legitimate question and answer, it's not only a typo, it's an error that can happens. If not we have to close all laravel question where the OP use a query with ->get() instead of ->first() or the other way around, and are a lot.

Answer (score 0):

change route

```
Route::get('/documents/{document}', 'DocumentsController@view')->name('documents.view');
```

to

```
Route::get('/documents-view/{document}', 'DocumentsController@view')->name('documents.view');
```